# No data returned in fragment after passing from activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass data from an activity to a fragment. I have this activityA which uses a fragment as a layout.

Now, when I tried to pass data from the activity to the fragment, I keep getting null. I even debugged and found out that the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` is null. I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("params", s);
        // set MyFragment Arguments
        Camera2BasicFragment myObj = new Camera2BasicFragment();
        myObj.setArguments(bundle);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();


        }
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String s  = getArguments().getString("params");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add code of `Camera2BasicFragment`.

Answer (score 2):

You created new instance when doing transaction. Just use the same instance for transaction. Do it this way .

```
  Camera2BasicFragment myObj = new Camera2BasicFragment();
    myObj.setArguments(bundle);
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, myObj)
                .commit();
```

And if you are using singleton pattern for fragment then you have to get the instance once and set bundle data to it .

```
 Camera2BasicFragment myObj = Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance();
    myObj.setArguments(bundle);
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, myObj)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 objects of **Camera2BasicFragment** class. One where you are setting arguments 
1)

```
Camera2BasicFragment myObj = new Camera2BasicFragment();
myObj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And
2)

```
Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance()
```

while replacing fragment. Use only one instance of Camera2BasicFragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your fragment

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        String s = bundle.getString("params");
    }
}
```